# Call a JavaScript function from jinja2 template for loop button

Tags: javascript, jinja2

I am learning Jinja and JS. I have few submit buttons created via for loop in Jinja template:

```
{% for item in items %}
<input type="submit" value="Place your Order" class="submit-class" />
{% endfor %}
```

I want to call JavaScript when any of the button is clicked. I tried below but it gives me error

**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at window.onload
**

Here is my JS code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector(".submit-class").addEventListener("click", function() {console.log("liked this product");
        });
};
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because wwindwo onload works before html has rendered so there are no items yet. You can try (I haven't run the code by the way):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var item = document.querySelector(".submit-class");
    if (item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {console.log("liked this product");});
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you @giraycoskun. Looks like I was missing a small logic here. Since the buttons were created via for loop, in function also I needed to use for loop. This solved my issue.